# Dynamic list box using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have never worked with Jquery and researched that the solution to my problem is through jquery only, So can any one help..

I have 4 list box having data that i need to fetch from sql database. two list box have data from  table A and other two have data from table B. Basically my form will give two options to select so i created two list box for each item.like two preferred games(football,basketball,tennis ... etc) on two preferred days (like Mon,Tue,Wed...etc)

Now the challenge I am facing is how to write a jquery so that if football is chosen as first game and Mon is chosen as preferred day, then on second option these two should not be available on list items.

Comment: (1) jQuery is *not* your only option.  Though it certainly is an easy one.  It's worth using in this case, but just be aware that it's not *the only thing* that can do this.  (2) At a high level what you're looking to do is create a "change" handler for your form elements which will examine the value of the changed element and disable that value in the other element.  You are encouraged to try *something* on your own.  Start by creating the `.change()` handler.  jQuery's documentation has examples on how that works and what it does.  See what you can accomplish, you might be surprised.

Comment: jQuery is just a JS library, so to say it's required to achieve something is an overstatement. It's *easier* to achieve something  (most of the time).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Dynamic-Dependent-Dropdown-List-Plugin-With-jQuery-linkedSelect.html and  https://hungred.com/how-to/tutorial-jquery-select-box-manipulation-plugin/
it has some info about dynamic stacks on jquery